# Issue with tcp connection in service

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I Created a Service to recieve data from a specific client. This works fine and im recieveing most of the data i want. However after 2-4 hours of the connection i get this error on the StreamReader.ReadLine, after this error occurs, the service start taking 90-99% of the cpu, and can only be closed using cmd and Taskkill.

> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
>      at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>      at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer()
>      at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadLine()

The code for the connection:

```
    static readonly object _lock = new object();
    List<Task> _connections = new List<Task>();
    private static string strConn;
    private static int _port;

    public async Task connectClients()
    {
        TcpListener ServerSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, _port);
        ServerSocket.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient client = await ServerSocket.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            var task = handle_clients(client);

            if (task.IsFaulted)
                task.Wait();

        }
    }

 private async Task handle_clients(TcpClient client)
    {
        var connectionTask = HandleConnectionAsync(client);

        lock (_lock)
            _connections.Add(connectionTask);

        try
        {
            await connectionTask;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            new LogWriter(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            // remove pending task
            lock (_lock)
            {
                _connections.Remove(connectionTask);
                client.GetStream().Close();
                client.Close();
            }

        }
    }  
    private async Task HandleConnectionAsync(TcpClient client)
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {                    
                string data = reader.ReadLine();
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data))
                {
                    Thread t = new Thread(() => DatabaseFix(data));
                    t.Start();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                new LogWriter(ex.ToString());
                break;
            }


        }

    }
```

So what i expect to happen when the connection get closed for whatever reason, it should shut down the connection, and then get a new connection?

Could this be some internet error "Firewall" between the client and the service? In this case what could be the error?

Comment: yes, you will need to handle reopening when connection lost.  there's more than a few reasons (beyond programmatic control) why network connections are dropped.  One right off the top of my head is wireless lease renewal.  Also sometimes packets are broken up, you will need to handle a single message not arriving all in 1 piece.  (Also hint: with network better to read direct from the socket - avoids stream buffering which basically only adds another layer of transfer interference.).

Comment: When i get the error that the connection was closed. The code should shutdown the client as of how the code is atm? Then the client would automaticly get connected again through the TcpListener? 
If i restart the service after error, the client can connect again, however if i dont restart it the client just never connects again. Were is the different? Since the tcplistener is always there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people interrested. The problem was that the client kept sending connection and closing them again untill it had any data to send. My code did not shutdown networkstream when error on client connection.

Changed my HandleConnectionAsync to this.

```
 try
        {
            using (var stream = client.GetStream())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    var data = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    DatabaseFix(data);

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            new LogWriter(ex.ToString());
        }
```